# Puh array in empty array that create before

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I push two Array in one Array But can't use them as a string,This result in bellow about two arrays in one array :

```
Array(0) [] //This is empty array that I create before and push these two array bellow to them 
length:2
0:Array(1) ["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788"]
1:Array(1) ["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788"]
```

and I create a for for access them but I can ! I write this code "

```
for(var index = 0 ; index < Array.length ; ++index) {
  let Each_String_In_Brackets = Array[index] ;
  console.log(Each_String_In_Bruckets);
}
```

Why is this happen!

I mean Why when we push array in empty array can't access them!
I want to access the content of them, I have a string  In each bracket.

Comment: It can be accessed. What do you mean you can't?

Comment: with my code I can't , How I can access them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var arr = [];
   arr.push(["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788"]);
   arr.push(["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788"]);

   //assuming inside array always will be one element:
   arr.forEach((item)=>{ console.log(item[0])})

   //if inside array may be multiple elements, then use this
   arr.forEach((item, index)=>{
      item.forEach((child)=>{ console.log(child)})
   })
```

Comment: In this code just return me back this: ["cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788"] , I need to back this : "cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788"

Comment: I am assuming inside array always will be one element, correct me if i am wrong arr.forEach((item)=>{ console.log(item[0])})

Answer (score 0):

pushing a full array into another array makes it a 2D array ( at the indexes where you push another array ) so for example if I have the first array

```
BArray[]
```

But if I push another array into it

```
BArray2 = [1,2,3,4];
BArray.push(Array2);
```

We would not be able to access it just by

```
BArray[0]
```

This would **return** the entire **array2** rather the content of **array2** at index 0.
Therefore you would do this

```
BArray[0][0]
```

So this would give us ( from your array ) `"cfdb9868-0f69-5781-b1e4-793301280788"`

If you would like to just dump out the content of `BArray2` into `BArray`
You can use the spread operator.

```
BArray[...BArray2];
```

( Also I would not use Array as variable name ! It can be confusing as `new Array(10);` is a way of creating arrays and having arrays with that name isn't best practice ! )

Hope this helps !

Comment: If I have more than one array in BArray ? how I can access to them ? I should create for ()?

Comment: for(let i = 0 ; i < BArray.length ; i++ ) {
     for(let j = 0 ; j < BArray[i].length ; j++ ) {
          console.log(BArray[i][j]); }
}

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing array in array, so you must access as 2D array:

```js
var array = [];
var arrayString1 = ["StringInArray1"],
  arrayString2 = ["StringInArray2"];
array.push(arrayString1);
array.push(arrayString2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));

array.forEach(arrayItem => {
  console.log("StringInArray: " + arrayItem[0]);
})
```

Or maybe you want to append array:

```js
var array = [];
var arrayString1 = ["StringInArray1"],
  arrayString2 = ["StringInArray2"];
[].push.apply(array, arrayString1);
[].push.apply(array, arrayString2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));

array.forEach(arrayItem => {
  console.log("StringInArray: " + arrayItem);
})
```

Comment: If I want remove empty bracket because I use it and have several bracket like this How I can remove them ? [ ] ,[ ]

Comment: @ Darius If I want remove empty bracket because I use it and have several bracket like this How I can remove them ? [ ] ,[ ]

Comment: I can't follow you. I'd suggest you to formulate new question, what you have and what you want

Comment: when I use your code in my program . I got the result but I have some empty bracket near my result. Imagine , what you write like this ["StringInArray1","StringInArray2"] and have [ ] , [ ] too . I guess in each line I searching for something especial and when in each line can't find it show me like this: [ ]

Comment: Without example I cant't exactly reproduce your mind. As I understand if you are pushing empty arrays, you must check it before pushing `if (arrayString.length) array.push(arrayString)`, or filter result removing empty arrays like: `array = array.filter(item => item.length)`. It is difficult to make suggestions without knowing exactly what you have and what you want.